# Returning an Eloquent model as JSON in Laravel 4

Tags: php, json, api, laravel, laravel-4

How do you return an Eloquent model to the browser as JSON? What is the difference between the two methods below? Both seems to work.

**#1:**

```
return Response::json($user->toArray());
```

**#2:**

```
return $user->toJson();
```

Answer (score 36):

The actual data sent is the same, however...

#1 Sends `Content-Type:application/json` to the browser

#2 Sends `Content-Type:text/html`

#1 is more correct but it depends on your Javascript, see: [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type)

However, it is much simpler to just return the model. It is automagically returned as JSON and the Content-Type is set correctly:

```
return $model;
```

Answer (score 12):

`Response::json($someArray)` is a generic way to return JSON data.

`return $model->toJson()` is specific to returning a model as JSON. This would be my preferred approach when working with an Eloquent model.

Answer (score 10):

In #1 you first convert your Eloquent to an array, and then you convert it to JSON, which seems a bit redundant.

With that in mind, I'd go with #2 if you're returning the JSON to the caller.

Also note that, in L4, whenever an Eloquent model is cast to a string it will be automatically converted to JSON. Hence, you can do like in this example from the documentation to return JSON data directly from your route:

```
Route::get('users', function()
{
    return User::all();
});
```

For more information, see http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json

Comment: This appears with me: `The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.`

Answer (score 1):

this solved my problem in laravel 5.5:

```
function allUsers()
{
    $users = \App\User::all();
    $usersJson = json_encode($users);
    return $usersJson;
}
```