# Reading Laravel JSON response in jQuery $.ajax

Tags: ajax, json, laravel

I'm facing strange problem when reading Laravel's json response. Here is my code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getallpoints',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(r){

            var lat = r.lat;
            var lng = r.lng;
            var status = r.status;

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                map: map
            });
        }
    });
```

Here is my Laravel code

In routes.php

```
Route::get('/getallpoints', 'PointController@getallpoints');
```

In PointController.php

```
class PointController extends BaseController {

public function getAllPoints(){

    return Point::all();
}
}
```

I'm getting undefined for these:

```
var lat = r.lat;
var lng = r.lng;
```

I also tried `Response::json(Point::all())` but the same error.

Comment: Please, consider reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602129/returning-an-eloquent-model-as-json-in-laravel-4

Comment: @delmadord I checked that already, tried all the possibilities. It looks like Laravel returns json data as can be seen in firebug but javascript is having problem. I even used $.parseJSON but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return Point::all();` will return an array of data, not one point, therefore you have to iterate through that data in your `success` callback:

```
...
success: function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var r = data[i];
        ...
    }
}
...
```

Comment: No problem at all. When working with APIs I find it very useful to test them with [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-packa/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) first and only then deal with responses in JavaScript