# Angular JS with Laravel -- How to Bind Eloquent ORM array To View

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-4, eloquent

I tried to Bind Laravel Eloquent ORM array to Angular JS View.

This is my code,

**controller (Laravel)**

```
public function index()
{
    $data = User::all();

    Response::json(array('data'=>$data));
}
```

View (Laravel)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Laravel PHP Framework</title>
<script type="text/javascript" href="{{URL::asset('js/angular.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  href="{{URL::asset('js/controller.js')}}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="welcome">
    <ul ng-controller="clientList">
        <li ng-repeat="clients as clients">{{clients.name}}</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Controller (Anular JS)

```
var anguApp = angular.module('anguApp', []);

anguApp.controller('clientList',function($scope,$http)
{

   $scope.clients=[];

   $http.get('/').success(function (data, status) {
   $scope.clients = data;
   console.log(data);
});
});
```

Now getting a blank screen in browser....
How to solve this ?

Comment: change `Response::json(array('data'=>$data));` into this `return Response::json(array('data'=>$data));`, might work.

Comment: how to show this with angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you shouldn't wrap the results of `User::all();` into an array.
That is, it is enough to do the pass the results of it directly:

`Response::json($data->toArray());`

Also, you need to return whatever the Laravel controller does so:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();

    return Response::json($users->toArray());
}
```

**Update:**

Or, following [Returning an Eloquent model as JSON in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602129/returning-an-eloquent-model-as-json-in-laravel-4), you can also return the model itself so:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();

    return $users;
}
```

**Update 2:**

Pretty sure your AngularJS syntax is wrong, according to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) it is:

`<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>`

So your code should read:

```
<ul ng-controller="clientList">
    <li ng-repeat="client in clients">{{client.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to int

Comment: now getting json array. but how to show this with angular